# Generating dynamic data using join select query in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

We have a `select query` containing around 10 `tables`. using that `query` we are getting just `50 record`. We need to get 50k record. actually we dont have functional understanding to generate data into these tables.

Is there any possibility, we can create `insert` query to insert data into these 10 table using that `select` query even if there is no integrity of data. We just need volume testing for the env.

Suppose I have below query

```
select d.deptno, d.dname,e.ename from dept d, emp e where d.deptno=e.deptno(+);
```

is there anyway to create `insert query` for `emp` and `dept` with little modification of data? I mean we can increase the `id` by one for primary key of the tables and generate thousands of records? is it possible?

I am just thinking if anything like this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a list of numbers and just repeat inserts.  Assuming the primary key is automatically generated, you can generate however many numbers you want and just insert:

```
insert into emp ( . . . )
with n as (
      select level as n
      from dual
      connect by level + 1 < 100
     )
select . . .
from n;
```

Comment: @Mahima To generate a portion of consistent data you can also use [multitable insert](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9014.htm#i2121682), putting the same column value in both tables.

Comment: sure I will read about it. thanks you @astentx